# update a field on contact once i associate a account

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger

i wanted to update  a field on contact once i associate a account.

once accountcontactrelation is created i am checking if that relation role is Manager and if yes then only i wanted to update a contact field.

My query is how cani achieve this in before trigger .beacuse if i write after trigger then my trigger is calling twice.Please suggest

and in before insert i am not getting any ACR and if on update I change the ACR then still not getting ACR query

```
map<id,AccountContactRelation>acrmap=new map<id,AccountContactRelation >();

    for(AccountContactRelation acr: [Select id,ContactId,Role__c from AccountContactRelation where (Role__c='Manager) and contactid in:newconMap.keyset() ]) {
        acrmap.put(acr.contactid,acr);
    }

    for(contact con:newconMap.values()) {
        if(acrmap.containsKey(con.id))
            con.isManager__c = true;   
    }
```

Comment: Try using recursive control to avoid trigger fire more than once.

Answer (score 0):

In the trigger you can check what stage you are in and then only run code when you want it to.

```
trigger TriggerName on SObjectType (before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after update, after delete) {

 if (trigger.isBefore){
    if (trigger.isUpdate){
        //run your code here
        //for good practice and readability, call a class that has your code in it
    }
    else if (trigger.isInsert){
    }
    else if (trigger.isDelete){
    }
}
else if (trigger.isAfter){
    if (trigger.isUpdate){
    }
    else if (trigger.isInsert){
    }
    else if (trigger.isDelete){
    }
}
```